# What is the curl of this function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have a vector field $E(r,\theta,\phi)=E_re_r+E_{\theta}e_{\theta}+ E_{\phi}e_{\phi}$(the small e's are unit vectors) in spherical coordinates and I know what $\nabla \times E$ is. Now I multiply this by $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-k(n-r \cos(\theta))}}$, so that we get $\frac{E}{1 + e^{-k(n-r \cos(\theta))}}$.

I want to evaluate $$ \nabla \times \frac{E}{1 + e^{-k(n-r \cos(\theta))}}$$ Is there any way to evaluate this and use the fact that I know what $\nabla \times E$ is? So I do not want to go through the whole differentiation with the whole term again, as this was very cumbersome for $\nabla \times E$ already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following product rule identity would be useful here, assuming you can compute the gradient of your scalar function: $ \nabla \times (\phi \mathbf{A}) = \phi \nabla \times \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A} \times \nabla \phi $.

Comment: ah thank you and the cross product, is there anything different in spherical coordinates?

Comment: @Lipschitz Nope, basis vectors in spherical coordinates form an orthonormal triple just like cartesian basis vectors. So as long as you use a right-handed system, nothing changes.